# Delegate string values being evaluating as DateTIme?

Tags: vb.net, string, datetime, dictionary, delegates

I am using a delegate from threaded classes (instantiated objects) to call a waitgif method in which I am maintaining a dictionary of my own thread names.  (don't worry about ways to monitor active and closed threads -- as this is a custom method that I actually do a lot of bookkeeping with).

The problem is that the string ("currentwaitgifname") that is being sent to the delegate is being evaluated as DateTime and throwing an exception, even though the delegate has defined string definitions which are sent to method.   Do I need to look into predicates?

```
         Public Delegate Sub ShowWaitGifDelegate(ByRef CurrentWaitGifName As String, ByVal onoff As Boolean, ByVal left As Integer, ByVal top As Integer)
         Public NumWaitGifs As Integer = 0
         Public currentwaitgifname As String = ""


         Dim main As Form1 = CType(Application.OpenForms(0), Form1)
         main.Invoke(New ShowWaitGifDelegate(AddressOf main.waitgifimg),  currentwaitgifname, False, 0, 0) ' Exception here, with string currentwaitgifname being evaluated against DateTime

         Public Sub waitgifimg(ByRef currentwaitgifname As String, ByVal onoff As Boolean, ByVal left As Integer, ByVal top As Integer)
            If currentwaitgifname = "" Then Exit Sub
            If onoff = True Then
                NumWaitGifs += 1
                currentwaitgifname = wgname + CStr(NumWaitGifs)
                Call addthreadtodic(currentwaitgifname)
            End If
            If onoff = False Then
                Call removethreadfromdic(currentwaitgifname)
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub addthreadtodic(ByVal currentwaitgifname)
            If dicWaitgifThreads.ContainsKey(currentwaitgifname) = False Then
                dicWaitgifThreads.Add(currentwaitgifname, "")
            End If
            My.Settings.dicWaitgifThreads.Add(currentwaitgifname.ToString)
            My.Settings.Save()
        End Sub

        Public Sub removethreadfromdic(ByVal currentwaitgifname)
            If currentwaitgifname = "" Then Exit Sub
            For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dicWaitgifThreads
                dicWaitgifThreads.RemoveAt(kvp.Key.ToString)
                My.Settings.dicWaitgifThreads.RemoveAt(kvp.Key)
                GoTo savesettings
            Next
    savesettings:
            My.Settings.Save()
        End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.  Can you provide the actual error message?  Also, have you looked at the stack trace because the original exception may well have been thrown in the method that was invoked.

Comment: By the way, what's up with that `For Each` loop with the `GoTo`?  That's just going to perform one iteration and jump out.  At least use `Exit For` but that still renders the loop useless.  I guess the only reason I can see for that is to ignore the collection if it's empty and process only the first item otherwise.  You should still use `Exit For` even in that case though.

Comment: There was something else inside the loop for which a trigger was fired, causing the GoTo to be used -- there was an If Them inside the For Each kvp.   Still working on this and will look at the stack trace.